# What should be done to ensure that the keys do not remain in memory? Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

My code working no problem but when I take in setInterval, result.length = 0 after first Interval because this[key] remain in memory. How can I remove this keys or is There any different way ?

```
setInterval(() => {
  var emirArray = allEmir.get("blabla");
  var result = [];
  if (emirArray.length > 0) {
    emirArray.forEach(a => {
      var key = a.cNo + '|' + a.sCodeEmir + '|' + a.howMuch;
      if (!this[key]) {
        this[key] = {
          cNo: a.cNo,
          sCodeEmir: a.sCodeEmir,
          lot: a.lot,
          birim: 0
        }
        result.push(this[key]);

      }
      this[key].birim += 1;
    }, Object.create(null));

    lampMap.set('lamp', result)
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: So do not store your temporary thing with `this[xxxx]`, not sure what you think the `Object.create(null)` is doing with a forEach loop

Comment: Instead of using `this`, what prevents you from creating an object at the start of the function, and using that object? For example, `var unique = {};` right after `var result = [];`, and then `unique[key]` everywhere you currently have `this[key]`

Comment: I will try now . I'm new to this language and sometimes I'm confused.@epascarello I got this codes from another person and there is no explain about Object.create(null).